ARIMA model Using YYYY-WWW results to "No supported index is available. Prediction results will be given with an integer index beginning at `start`."
I'm encountering an issue while using the auto_arima function from the pmdarima library to train an ARIMA model on my weekly time series data. The data is structured with an ISO 8601 week-year format (YYYY-WWW) which only contains week and year information. Here's a snippet of the code where the problem occurs:
for barangay in barangayList:
    print("Training Barangay {}".format(barangay))
    # Filter data for the barangay
    barangay_data = dengueData[dengueData['Barangay'] == barangay].copy()  # Create a copy to avoid setting on a slice

    # Split week-year format to extract year and week
    barangay_data[['year', 'week']] = barangay_data['week_yearFormat'].str.split('-W', expand=True)

    # Convert to datetime directly using year and week
    barangay_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(
        barangay_data['year'].astype(str) + '-W' + barangay_data['week'].astype(str) + '-1',
        format='%G-W%V-%u',  # Correct format for week-year format
        errors='coerce'  # Handle parsing errors by setting to NaT
    )

    # Drop rows with NaT if any
    barangay_data.dropna(subset=['date'], inplace=True)

    if barangay_data.empty:
        print(f"Skipping {barangay} as it has no data.")
        continue

    # Set DateTimeIndex
    barangay_data.set_index('date', inplace=True)

    # Extract Dengue Cases as time series data
    time_series = barangay_data['Dengue Cases']

    # Fit ARIMA model
    model = auto_arima(
        time_series,
        seasonal=True,  # Set True if seasonal patterns are expected
        m=52,  # Weekly data (52 weeks in a year)
        trace=False,  # Set True to see model selection details
        error_action='ignore',
        suppress_warnings=True,
        stepwise=True  # Use stepwise search for efficiency
    )
    # Save the model for the barangay
    barangaysModel[barangay] = model

    # Forecast the next 12 weeks (example)
    n_periods = 4
    forecast, conf_int = model.predict(n_periods=n_periods, return_conf_int=True)
    forecast_results[barangay] = {
        'forecast': forecast,
        'conf_int': conf_int
    }


Any suggestions or corrections to the approach would be highly appreciated.
I have tried converting the week-year format into a datetime index directly using the pd.to_datetime() function:
barangay_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    barangay_data['year'].astype(str) + '-W' + barangay_data['week'].astype(str) + '-1',
    format='%G-W%V-%u',
    errors='coerce'
)

Desired Outcome:
I am seeking a solution to parse the week_yearFormat correctly so that I can successfully train the ARIMA model. The solution should handle the ISO week-year format appropriately and allow for fitting the ARIMA model using auto_arima from the pmdarima library.

In Pandas, there is a function called fromisocalendar which will transform an ISO 8601 year-week-day format to a TimeStamp:
pd.Timestamp.fromisocalendar(2024, 51, 3)

-> Timestamp('2024-12-18 00:00:00')
